# Add bibliographic entry by DOI without using bib-files

Tags: bibtex

This question is not about `org-bibtext`, `org-ref` or something like that which are all based on underlying existing `bib`-files.

I have a simple text-file (e.g. `*.org`) open in a buffer. I wan't to insert the full reference/bibliographic information of an article into it.

But I only have the DOI in my clipboard. I wan't to do something like this

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `insert-full-ref-by-doi 10.2147/CIA.S218367`

And then this should appear in the buffer of the text-file

> Buhtz, C., Paulicke, D., Schwarz, K., Jahn, P., Stoevesandt, D. &
> Frese, T. (2019). Receptiveness Of GPs In The South Of Saxony-Anhalt,
> Germany To Obtaining Training On Technical Assistance Systems For
> Caregiving. A Cross-Sectional Study. Clinical Interventions in Aging,
> 2019(14), 1649–1656. doi:10.2147/CIA.S218367

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this extensively, but, using the [citeproc-el library](https://github.com/andras-simonyi/citeproc-el), the function for fetching BibTeX entries based on DOIs at https://www.anghyflawn.net/blog/2014/emacs-give-a-doi-get-a-bibtex-entry/ can be adapted to insert a full formatted reference along the following lines (you need to replace "/path/to/dir_with_csl_locales" and "/path/to/a_csl_style.csl" with valid paths to a dir with CSL locales and to a CSL style):

```lisp
(require 'citeproc)
(require 'bibtex)

(defun insert-full-ref-by-doi (doi)
  "Insert a formatted reference of the item with DOI."
  (interactive "MDOI: ")
  (let* ((url-mime-accept-string "text/bibliography;style=bibtex")
         (lg (citeproc-locale-getter-from-dir 
              "/path/to/dir_with_csl_locales"))
         (csl-style
           (citeproc-create-style "/path/to/a_csl_style.csl" lg))
         bibtex-item)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         (format "http://dx.doi.org/%s"
          (replace-regexp-in-string "http://dx.doi.org/" "" doi)))
     (set-buffer-multibyte t)
     (goto-char (point-max))
     (re-search-backward "@")
     (beginning-of-line)
     (setq bibtex-item (bibtex-parse-entry))
     (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (let ((csl-item (citeproc-bt-entry-to-csl bibtex-item)))
      (insert (citeproc-render-item csl-item csl-style 'bib 'plain t)))))
```